# Block Windows Shutdown with Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, shutdown

I wanted to ask if it was possible to block or lengthen the windows shutdown process after starting it through a batch file.
This is my code:

```
@echo off
start shutdown.exe -s -t 1800
```

Thanks and excuse me for my bad english but I'm italian :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think `shutdown /a` will do what you ask.
I suggest you to read the man of the commend: just type it in a console and see what option is good for you.

Then to 'delay' the shutdown you can use the `/t` parameter and set a personalized delay (30" is default)

IT:
Prova con il comando scritto sopra, inoltre ti consiglio di leggere la descrizione di `shutdown` in cui ti spiega tutte le opzioni: apri un terminale e digiti 'shutdown' per avere la lista dei possibili argomenti. il parametro `/t` ti consente di specificare un ritardo alla chiamata di shutdown.

Comment: should be `/a` instead of `\a`